# Pandas Data frame to desired python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame which looks like following

```
 Date        Top      
            A    B
2018-09-30  1.2  2.3
2018-10-01  1.5  1.7
2018-10-02  2.3  2.8
2018-10-03  7.7  7.5
2018-10-04  1.1  0.9
2018-10-05  2.1  6.5
```

So I have multi-index in the columns, only two columns 'Date' and 'Top' and then 'Top' has two level 1 columns 'A' and 'B'.

I am trying to convert them into python dictionary.

when I am using

```
df_dict = df.to_dict(orient = 'index')
```

I get an output

```
{0: {('Top', 'A'): 1.2, ('Top', 'B'): 2.3, ('date', ''): '2018-09-30'},
1: {('Top', 'A'): 1.5, ('Top', 'B'): 1.7, ('date', ''): '2018-10-01'},
2: {('Top', 'A'): 2.3, ('Top', 'B'): 2.8, ('date', ''): '2018-10-02'},
3: {('Top', 'A'): 7.7, ('Top', 'B'): 7.5, ('date', ''): '2018-10-03'},
4: {('Top', 'A'): 1.1, ('Top', 'B'): 0.9, ('date', ''): '2018-10-04'},
5: {('Top', 'A'): 2.1, ('Top', 'B'): 6.5, ('date', ''): '2018-10-05'}}
```

Now I can access df_dict with following script which give me an output of 1.2

```
df_dict[1]['Top']['Top','A']
```

But I am looking for output with this script

```
df_dict[1]['Top']

Output: A:1.2, B:2.3
```

since 'Top' is not a key inside the first [1] key-value pair. So that I can access all 'Top' easily for a date.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict comprehension` with filtering by first level `Top`:

```
df_dict = df.to_dict(orient = 'index')
out = {k2: v for (k1, k2), v in df_dict[0].items() if k1 == 'Top'}
print (out)
{'A': 1.2, 'B': 2.3}
```

Simplier is use pandas for select by index value and first level of `MultiIndex` and then create `dict`:

```
print (df.loc[0, 'Top'])
A    1.2
B    2.3
Name: 0, dtype: object

out = df.loc[0, 'Top'].to_dict()
print (out)
{'A': 1.2, 'B': 2.3}
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
              A    B
2018-09-30  1.2  2.3
2018-10-01  1.5  1.7
2018-10-02  2.3  2.8
2018-10-03  7.7  7.5
2018-10-04  1.1  0.9
2018-10-05  2.1  6.5

df.index.name = 'date'
df = df.reset_index()
#set MultiIndex for each columns for avoid empty strings keys
df.columns = [['d','Top', 'Top'], df.columns]

#for each first level of MultiIndex create dictionary
#also add new level to outer level of dict 
out = {x:df[x].to_dict(orient = 'index') for x in df.columns.levels[0]}
print (out)
{'Top': {0: {'A': 1.2, 'B': 2.3}, 1: {'A': 1.5, 'B': 1.7}, 2: {'A': 2.3, 'B': 2.8}, 
         3: {'A': 7.7, 'B': 7.5}, 4: {'A': 1.1, 'B': 0.9}, 5: {'A': 2.1, 'B': 6.5}}, 
'd': {0: {'date': '2018-09-30'}, 1: {'date': '2018-10-01'}, 
      2: {'date': '2018-10-02'}, 3: {'date': '2018-10-03'}, 
      4: {'date': '2018-10-04'}, 5: {'date': '2018-10-05'}}}

print (out['Top'][0])
{'A': 1.2, 'B': 2.3}
```

Comment: I want to create a dictionary which I can call as df_dict[1]['top'] for all the groups, can I create my pandas dataframe in such as way that when I convert it in the dictionary, it can be called as desired. But, truly thanks for investing your time

Comment: @ManuSharma - is order important? `df_dict['Top'][0]` is possible use?

Comment: yeah, this is how I was thinking, though not imp, but that will take the top in index? because I can have 100 of them

Comment: @ManuSharma - then use `df.columns = [['d'] + ['Top'] * 2, df.columns]`, then change `2` by number of columns